# ClassNotFoundException for javax.xml.bind.JAXBException with Spring Boot when switch to Java 9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-9

Initialized the project using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io)

Added **WEB,JPA,H2** dependencies then tried to run the `MainApplication.java` using `Jdk 9` and got the following **error log**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-02-26 16:23:33.973  INFO 3860 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on RAJAT-PC with PID 3860 (C:\Users\devra\Downloads\Compressed\demo\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by rajat in C:\Users\devra\Downloads\Compressed\demo\target)
2018-02-26 16:23:33.973  INFO 3860 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-26 16:23:34.254  INFO 3860 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1aa7ecca: startup date [Mon Feb 26 16:23:34 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/C:/Users/devra/Downloads/Compressed/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-02-26 16:23:38.429  INFO 3860 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c55a85e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-26 16:23:39.856  INFO 3860 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-26 16:23:39.888  INFO 3860 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-26 16:23:39.903  INFO 3860 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-02-26 16:23:40.247  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-26 16:23:40.247  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6024 ms
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-02-26 16:23:40.622  INFO 3860 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2018-02-26 16:23:42.200  INFO 3860 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-26 16:23:42.263  INFO 3860 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2018-02-26 16:23:42.591  INFO 3860 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-02-26 16:23:42.607  INFO 3860 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-02-26 16:23:42.607  INFO 3860 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-02-26 16:23:42.653  WARN 3860 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2018-02-26 16:23:42.669  INFO 3860 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-26 16:23:42.716  INFO 3860 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-26 16:23:42.747 ERROR 3860 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Then I switched to jdk 8 and it working fine.

The same happening with **Spring-boot 2.0.0 RC2**

Why this happening when spring doc mentioned the required Java version for it to be 8 or 9.

Comment: Not related to the actual solution but I suggest to use Spring Boot 2 (due release on 27th Feb 2018) as Spring Boot 1.5 doesn't officially support JDK 9

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to add the JAXB dependency (as not provided any longer by default in Java 9) and **you have to** use Spring Boot 2 :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Note that if you use Java 10, you would have exactly the same issue as the JAXB dependency removal was not done just for the Java 9 version.

---

[The Spring Boot wiki about Java 9 and above](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above) lists things that you need to know to run Spring Boot apps on Java 9 and above.

### Spring Boot version requirements

- Spring Boot 1 doesn't support it (and no planned to).
- Spring Boot 2 supports it.

> Spring Boot 2 is the first version to support Java 9 (Java 8 is also
> supported). If you are using 1.5 and wish to use Java 9 you should
> upgrade to 2.0 as we have no plans to support Java 9 on Spring Boot
> 1.5.x.

**Java 10** is supported as of Spring Boot **2.0.1.RELEASE** while **Java 11** is supported as of Spring Boot **2.1.0.M2**.

### Some known workarounds

#### AspectJ

> With Java 9, if you need to weave classes from the JDK, you need to
> use AspectJ 1.9. Spring AOP should work fine in most cases with
> AspectJ 1.8 (the default in Spring Boot 2.0).

#### JAXB

> When upgrading you may face the following:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>
> Hibernate typically requires JAXB that’s no longer provided by
> default. You can add the java.xml.bind module to restore this
> functionality with Java9 or Java10 (even if the module is deprecated).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

As of Java11, the module is not available so your only option is to add the JAXB RI (you can do that as of Java9 in place of adding the `java.xml.bind` module:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

#### Lombok

If you are using lombok, the managed version of Spring Boot may not work with the latest JDK. Check the Lombok web site and override its version if necessary.

### Some known limitations

> These libraries do not have full support for Java 9 yet:
>
> - Apache Cassandra, see #10453

---

Please, don't hesitate to edit this post if changes occur about the Java 9 and above compatibility with Spring Boot.

Comment: Seems like it's not necessary as of Spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE & Java11 (AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)).

Answer (score 8):

Added below dependency and resolve the issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: i faced same issue with Mule plugin and after adding above plugin I get more..[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) on project json-logger: Error executing: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

Comment: I added other libraries too as santhose subramani said..but issue is not resolved.Execution default-extension-model of goal org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.1:extension-model failed: A required class was missing while executing org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.1:extension-model: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Answer (score 2):

Add below maven dependencies in you pom.xml and the issue will get resolve. in Java9/10 JaxB modules has been removed, hence need to add manually.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.11</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, i am using this solution based on Java12 with the versions 1.2.0 (java.activation) and for the rest 2.3.0. But i will get the Error "module <packagename> reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2 from both jaxb.core and jaxb.impl" in module-info.java. Anyone can help me? Hint: I have added in this module-info: "requires java.activation / jaxb.impl and jaxb.core".

Comment: @Alex Did you fix this issue? Waht are the dependencies you used? can you post your full dependency list with version number?

Comment: I added all above dependencies..but i get following issue is not resolved.Execution default-extension-model of goal org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.1:extension-model failed: A required class was missing while executing org.mule.runtime.plugins:mule-extensions-maven-plugin:1.1.1:extension-model: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Answer (score 2):

Or for Gradle add the dependency

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
```

Comment: For people having issues with java 1.8 not being their default JRE or they have multiple java versions and want to run a program using java 1.8 you can Run a JAR file using a specific JRE by:
  `<path_to_jre>/bin/java -jar Executable.jar` (You can put this in .bat [Windows] or .bash [macOS] file to run directly)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is right, just wanted to point out I was having the same issue during Tomcat 9 startup while migrating a web project to OpenJDK11. In my case got the following stack trace:

```
SEVERE [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment:
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
               at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
               at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
               at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)
               at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.collectAnnotatedFields(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:245)
               at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.getBeanInfo(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:154)
               at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.process(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:140)
               at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.push(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:126)
               at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.AnnotationManager.applyConfigAnnotations(AnnotationManager.java:234)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:449)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:245)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:121)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:127)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:118)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:403)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:138)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
               at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:246)
               at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:443)
               at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4684)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5147)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
               at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
               at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
               at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
               at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
               at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
               at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
               at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
               ... 65 more
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

@Ratha : For Java12 (referred to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986999/classnotfoundexception-for-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-with-spring-boot-when-sw/60371962#comment106790145_52019668)) this dependency list works:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <...>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```