# can't generate allure report data in Java 10 using maven

Tags: java, maven, allure

I am trying to generate an allure report using the command `mvn allure:report` in Java 10.0.1 but I keep getting the error:

```
[INFO] Generate report to /home/ken/target/site/allure-maven-plugin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.xmlFiles(Allure1Plugin.java:375)
    at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.getStreamOfAllure1Results(Allure1Plugin.java:370)
    at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readResults(Allure1Plugin.java:101)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.lambda$readResults$0(ReportGenerator.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.readResults(ReportGenerator.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1492)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:54)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:43)
    at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:88)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:358)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] Can't generate allure report data
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:153)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureCommandline.execute (AllureCommandline.java:88)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureCommandline.generateReport (AllureCommandline.java:59)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.generateReport (AllureGenerateMojo.java:213)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.executeReport (AllureGenerateMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate (AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute (AbstractMavenReport.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.965 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-12T17:18:44-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:2.9:report (default-cli) on project front-end-test: An error has occurred in Allure report generation.: Could not generate the report: Can't generate allure report data: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I know that the first error is because of the jaxb-api dependency (I have added all the dependencies to my pom.xml but still getting this error) but my main concern is the second error which prevents the report from being generated.

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.10</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.2</aspectj.version>
    <dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0
        </version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I have the same project on another PC with java 8 and I don't have an issue generating a report. I went through other similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986999/classnotfoundexception-for-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-with-spring-boot-when-sw/

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk as you can see in my pom.xml, I have added the jaxb-api dependency and I am still seeing the issue. However, my concern here is the allure report not being generated

Comment: May you try to add `jaxb-api` dependency to the `allure-maven` by following this guide? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, here's what you can do; Try removing the listener property from the surefire plugin, instead you can write up a specific listener class and use that with an @Listener on you test class. This should work with you maven command run. Although not sure why this issue happens only with maven but works for testNG.