# Get error when run project restfulapi in spring-boot

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I am beginer with java and Spring boot and when i build simple project restfulapi web, when i run this project i get error!
here my struct of project :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRkUo.png)

here my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>me.loda.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-learning</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-learning</name>
    <description>Everything about Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--spring mvc, rest-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>restfulapi.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here my controller file:

```
package restfulapi.controller;

import java.util.List;
import restfulapi.model.UserRepository;
import restfulapi.model.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.*;


/**
 * Copyright 2019 {@author Loda} (https://loda.me).
 * This project is licensed under the MIT license.
 *
 * @since 5/25/2019
 * Github: https://github.com/loda-kun
 */

/**
 * Lưu ý, @RequestMapping ở class, sẽ tác động tới tất cả các RequestMapping ở
 * bên trong nó.
 *
 * Mọi Request ở trong method sẽ được gắn thêm prefix /api/v1
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class RestApiController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userrepository;

    // bạn còn nhớ @PostConstruct dùng để làm gì chứ?
    // nếu không nhớ, hãy coi lại bài viết Spring Boot #3 nhé

    @GetMapping("/todo")
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        List<User> user = userrepository.findAll();
        return user;
    }

    /*
     * phần path URL bạn muốn lấy thông tin sẽ để trong ngoặc kép {}
     */
    @GetMapping("/user/{userId}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable(name = "userId") Integer userId) {
        // @PathVariable lấy ra thông tin trong URL
        // dựa vào tên của thuộc tính đã định nghĩa trong ngoặc kép /todo/{todoId}
        User user = userrepository.findById(userId).get();
        return user;
    }

    /*
     * @RequestBody nói với Spring Boot rằng hãy chuyển Json trong request body
     * thành đối tượng Todo
     */
    @PutMapping("/user/{userId}")
    public User editUser(@PathVariable(name = "userId") Integer userId, @RequestBody User u) {
        User user = userrepository.update(userId, u.getName(), u.getAge(), u.getEmail());

        return user;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteUser(@PathVariable(name = "userId") Integer userId) {
        userrepository.deleteById(userId);
        if (userrepository.existsById(userId))
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("Error Message");

        else
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("dalate success!");
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity addUser(@RequestBody User u) {
        // Trả về response với STATUS CODE = 200 (OK)
        // Body sẽ chứa thông tin về đối tượng todo vừa được tạo.
        User user = userrepository.save(u);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }
}
```

here my user file:

```
package restfulapi.model;

import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data 
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -297553281792804396L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name =  "user_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name =  "name")
    private String name;

    private int age;

    private String email;


}
```

here UserRepository.java file:

```
package restfulapi.model;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;


import restfulapi.model.User;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository <User, Integer> {



    @Query(value = "update users set name = :name, age =:age , email = :email  where user_id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    User update(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("name") String name, @Param("age") Integer age, @Param("email") String email);

}
```

my app.java file just simple:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

here my log error:

```
2019-11-23 13:50:51.016  INFO 3454 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at restfulapi.App.main(App.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:497) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
        at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:688) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1269) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
        ... 50 common frames omitted

2019-11-23 13:50:51.021  INFO 3454 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@6658d730
2019-11-23 13:50:51.400  WARN 3454 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
2019-11-23 13:50:51.400  INFO 3454 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-11-23 13:50:51.442  INFO 3454 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-11-23 13:50:51.446  INFO 3454 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-11-23 13:50:51.482  INFO 3454 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-23 13:50:51.486 ERROR 3454 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 48 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
  at restfulapi.App.main (App.java:25)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister (PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister (PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize (MetamodelImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init> (SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1265)
    at restfulapi.App.main (App.java:25)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer (EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer (EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init> (EntityMetamodel.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init> (AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init> (SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible (SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3 (DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2 (DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass (DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass (FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3 (ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2 (ProxyFactory.java:515)
  at restfulapi.App.main (App.java:25)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.190 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-23T13:50:51+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

sombody can help me?? thank a lot!

Comment: Basically, you need to add the dependency for jaxb-api. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986999/classnotfoundexception-for-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-with-spring-boot-when-sw

Comment: Either you need to add jax b dependency or you have dependency version collision. Run mvn dependency:tree -DVerbose to see omitted versions. This should be good starting point

Comment: Several things. Upgrade to most recent version of Spring Boot (2.2.1.RELEASE)...also add jaxb-api dependency cause it looks like you are running on JDK 11?? and no it's not a version collision...

Comment: why i need to add the dependency for jaxb-api in this case. When i buil a simple restfulapi with no database and i do'nt hava the dependency for jaxb-api and that still work.  that project i following code in the [link](https://github.com/loda-kun/spring-boot-learning/tree/master/spring-boot-14-restful-api-%40RestController-%40RequestBody-%40PathVariable)  @VKJava

Comment: why i need to add the dependency for jaxb-api in this case. When i buil a simple restfulapi with no database and i do'nt hava the dependency for jaxb-api and that still work.  that project i following code in the [link](https://github.com/loda-kun/spring-boot-learning/tree/master/spring-boot-14-restful-api-%40RestController-%40RequestBody-%40PathVariable)  @khmarbaise